# Seen function, like here on SO

Tags: php, mysql, date

i need and advice and example, how i can build a function, or something else for displaying a "seen" status, like here on SO (in users tab).I know it should be with user reg + log system, and i have already did this, but i need exactly this option...to display seen ...

Comment: Well you would need to (1) record when they were seen. (2) Display it on the web page. What aspect do you have a question about?

Answer (score 2):

> Hello guys, i need and advice and
>   example, how i can build a function,
>   or something else for displaying a
>   "seen" status, like here on SO (in
>   users tab)

Check out:

- [Pretty Date by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/)

**Examples:**

```
prettyDate("2008-01-28T20:24:17Z") // => "2 hours ago"
prettyDate("2008-01-27T22:24:17Z") // => "Yesterday"
prettyDate("2008-01-26T22:24:17Z") // => "2 days ago"
prettyDate("2008-01-14T22:24:17Z") // => "2 weeks ago"
```

Comment: This is useful, but let me try to explain... i want to know when i should reset this "seen" timer and when i should start it?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't only use PHP, you would need a database(like MySQL) to store the state, such as seen. You would most likely want to set up a many-to-many table such as:

Seen Table(id, user_id, post_id)

It is many to many because:

A user can see many posts, and a post can be seen by many users.

Comment: The SO "seen" function just records the dattetime of their last activity AFAIK.

Comment: I'm talking about this "seen    25sec ago" into your user tab...